# How to extract recipients email id from email intent in android after user has sent mail using android app?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I have created an app which alows user to send mails. The message text is prefilled with data from the app. I would like to know the recipient email ids the user send the mail to. Is it possible for me to get back recipient email ids when user sends mail using email Intent.

Comment: final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

Comment: I believe you can't. email app does not broadcast any intent containing recipient information, after sending email.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for me to get back recipient email ids when user sends mail using email Intent.

Fortunately, this is not possible, as this would be a significant privacy violation.